# Is shared object compiled for 32bit or 64bit machine?

Tags: linux, shared-objects

Is there a command in Linux that we can run on a compiled shared object(.so) in /usr/lib and know whether it is compiled for 64 bit or 32 bit system? (I mean to know ELF class, like ELFCLASS32)

Comment: `file /usr/lib/libxx.so`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [`file`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) command. E.g.:

```
[myuser@mycomputer]$ file /usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.1.1 
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.4.1.1: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, stripped
```